# autologin with xfce

Tags: debian, xfce, autologin

How do I do automatically login to an xfce session?

I'm using Debian 11 xfce on a client, but he's not liking to login. So I wanted to make it automatic.

Answer (score 3):

How to do this depends on what display manager you're using.

For example, on my mythtv box (which also happens to be a Debian machine running `xfce`), I am using [lightdm](https://launchpad.net/lightdm), and I want the `mythtv` user to automatically login after a 10 second delay (to give me an opportunity to login as another user).

To achieve this, I have the following in the `[SeatDefaults]` section of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
autologin-user = mythtv
autologin-user-timeout = 10
```

The above **only works for `lightdm`**.  If you're using a different display manager (e.g. `gdm3`, `lxdm`, `sddm`, or one of several others), you will have to read the documentation to find out a) if they support automatic login, and b) how to do it.

---

IMO you would be better off teaching your client that having to log in is for his safety - nobody can access their data unless they know the login name and the password.

auto-login features are intended more for kiosk-like situations (where a PC is running as an appliance), not really to bypass basic security.